# autohotkey hold left mouse down at all times

Tags: autohotkey

I am currently trying to achieve the following with my Xbox 360 controller on my PC :

if the JoyX or JoyY positions get out of the center (50) by at least 10 , so must be less then 40 or more then 60 to occur.

I need it to hold down the mouse and meanwhile be able to move the mouse position according to the joystick movements. The left mouse button must go up when the JoyX and/or JoyY are within the 40 / 60 range.

so far i have :

```
if(ismousedown = 1)
{
    Send % "{Click " . ( GetKeyState("LButton") ? "Up}" : "Down}" )
    ismousedown = 0
}

if(joyx > 60 || joyx < 40 || joyy > 60 || joyy < 40)
{

    ismousedown = 1

    MouseMove, mousex, mousey

}
else
{
    ismousedown = 0
}
```

but this does not work since the movement check of the joystick is within an unending loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the infinite loop, you'll need to place your controls within a subroutine with a timer value set. There are a couple other issues as well

- The X and Y movements of the joystick should be separated
- Mouse down should have a timer to prevent a down/up loop

Here is what I wrote. I tested it by dragging my desktop icons around. It's hardly optimal, but it should be a good starting point:

```
#SingleInstance
#Persistent
#NoEnv 
SendMode Input 

SetTimer, WatchJoystick, 10 

GetKeyState, JoyInfo, JoyInfo

return  

WatchJoystick:
IsMouseDown := false
GetKeyState, joyx, joyx
GetKeyState, joyy, joyy

if joyx > 60
{
  IsMouseDown := true
  MouseX := joyx - 60
}
else if joyx < 40
{
  IsMouseDown := true
  MouseX := joyx - 40
} else {
  MouseX = 0
}
if joyy > 60
{
  IsMouseDown := true
  MouseY := joyy - 60
}
else if joyy < 40
{
  IsMouseDown := true
  MouseY := joyy - 40
} else {
  MouseY = 0
}
if IsMouseDown
{
  Click down
  SetTImer, WaitForJoyCenter, 10
  SetMouseDelay, -1
  MouseMove, MouseX, MouseY, 0, R
}

WaitForJoyCenter:
if (joyx < 40 || joyx > 60 || joyy < 40 || joyy > 60)
  return

Click up
SetTimer, WaitforJoyCenter, off
return
```